# 'this' behaves differently

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var x = 3;

var obj1 = {
   x:2,
   obj2:{
      x:1,
      fun: function() {
         console.log(this.x);
      }
   }
}

var exec = obj1.obj2.fun;
exec();
obj1.obj2.fun();
```

Why the above code returns `3` and `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the `exec()` function calls it refer the `this` as window object. So that it is displaying 3 as output. Because the global `x` variable has the value 3.

When the `obj1.obj2.fun()` function calls it refer the `this` is obj2 object. So that it is displaying 1 as output. Because obj2 has it is own property x with the value 1.

You can get more clarity about `this` here. [understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var exec = obj1.obj2.fun
```

This statement returns the reference of the function. Not the value that the function returns.

Now when you call exec(), it will run the function but will take the value of the global variable x.

so basically if you console.log exec, it will show you the function code, not the value.

In the last line, you are actually executing the function from within the object, so it returns the value of obj2.x.